# Add group indexers to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
date_time, user, page
12345, A, index
13456, A, index
14566, B, home
...
```

I'd like to store the index of each row (i.e., its order when sorted by date_time), both overall, and per page.

Overall is simple. Just something like:

```
df['overall_count'] = range(len(df))
```

But I can't figure out how to do it for the pages. The following code gets me what I want, but it's connected to the groupby object, and I can't figure out how to move it to the main dataframe.

```py
grouped = df.groupby('page')
for name, group in grouped:
    group = group.sort_values('date_time')
    group['page_count'] = range(len(group))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign group-wise indices, you can use cumcount:

```
df.groupby('page').cumcount()
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm asking for - I want the index of where each row is within the group - not the total count of items in the group.

Comment: Your answer totally helped me to figure it out. What I want is:

`d['page_index'] = d.groupby('page')['page'].transform(lambda x: range(len(x)))`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Can you try `df.groupby('page').cumcount()` maybe?